# bigquery split string to chars

Tags: google-bigquery

Suppose I have a table, in which one of the columns is a string:

```
id    |    value
________________
1     |    HELLO
----------------
2     |      BYE
```

How would I split each STRING into it's chars, to create the following table:

```
id    |    value
________________
1     |     H
----------------
1     |     E
----------------
1     |     L
----------------
1     |     L
....
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SPLIT function with empty string as delimiter, i.e.

```
SELECT id, SPLIT(value, '') value FROM Table
```

Please note, that SPLIT returns repeated field, and if you want flat results (wasn't clear from your question), you would use

```
SELECT * FROM 
  FLATTEN((SELECT id, SPLIT(value, '') value FROM Table), value)
```

Comment: beat me by 16 second :)

Comment: Sorry Gil - I was actually still working on my answer, but hit "Post" prematurely, so technically you beat me.

Comment: Yeah, your edit saved me a second question :) What I really needed was the flattened results, and I am trying to join the data with a lookup table!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, if you pass an empty delimiter, it works:

```
select id, split(str, '')
from (
  select 1 as id, "HELLO" as str
)
```